# two arrays are synchronous change,Maybe a bug from VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two object list and `TEMP_ARR`. They are not the same in memory, but when I change one, the other changes. Very strange, maybe a bug from VUE.

http://jsfiddle.net/3yx2a9vk/4/

Comment: please add code tot he question, and try to describe the problem better

Comment: note, the arrays inside `TEMP_ARR` are the same arrays as in `list` - because that's how objects work in javascript - `this.list = TEMP_ARR.slice(0)` makes this.list a different array to `TEMP_ARR` .. but the elements of the array are the same elements (in your case, the arrays in each item of the main array) in other words, .slice does NOT do a deep copy - absolutely nothing to do with VUE, it has to do with your understanding of objects (including arrays) in javascript

Comment: you are right,thank you ~it's my fault,nothing to do with vue,sorry~~haha!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vue data are observable by default. If you assign one to another then it holds references. So, the solution is to create a new copy.

```
this.list = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(TEMP_ARR));
```